# How to spread elements with flex to take up the same width in a parent container

Tags: css, sass, flexbox

[My codepen](https://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/OaQVoM)

**What I want to achieve:**

I want that the elements within the process-indicator parent take up the same width except the elements with class=step AND that the divs with steps name are directly under the step element.

The process-indicator stretch 100% and the connector classes should not use fixed pixel widths so I can add 5,6 or 10 steps and it scales graphically well.

**What does not work:**

1.) The first after-connector and last before-connector elements in yellow do not share the same size as the elements in green/black

2.) The step names in the divs should be positioned under the according step bubble and not inline with the steps and connectors.

---

Be aware that I do **NOT** want to use the before/after pseudo selectors for the step element! =>

I need to be able to later apply dynamically a complete/incomplete class with react thus I need full control about every connector.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="process-indicator">
  <li class="completed">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="after-connector"></span>
    <div>step 1</div>
  </li>
  <li class="incompleted">
    <span class="before-connector"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
     <span class="after-connector"></span>
    <div>step 2</div>
  </li>
  <li class="incompleted">
    <span class="before-connector"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>    
    <span class="after-connector"></span>
    <div>step 3</div>
  </li>
  <li class="incompleted">
    <span class="before-connector"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>    
    <div>step 4</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**SCSS**

```
  $incomplete: gray;
$complete: blue;
$step-size: 40px;
$step-line-thickness: 2px;
$border-thickness: 1px;
$darken-amount: 30%;

@mixin step-style($color) {
  background-color: $color;
  color: $color;
  border-color: darken($color, $darken-amount);

  &:before,
  &:after {
    background-color: $color;
    border-color: darken($color, $darken-amount);
  }
}

.flex {
  -ms-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -moz-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}

.displayFlex {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.process-indicator {
  background: orange;
  @extend .displayFlex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1em;

  > li {
    @extend .displayFlex;
    @extend .flex;

    list-style: none;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    position: relative;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    color: $incomplete;
  }

  > li .before-connector,
  li .after-connector {
    @extend .flex;

    position: relative;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    color: $incomplete;
  }

  > li .step {
    width: $step-size;
    height: $step-size;
    background-color: $incomplete;
    border-radius: 40px;
  }
  // line connectors
  > li .after-connector {
    height: 3px;
    top: $step-size / 2;
    background-color: green;
  }
  > li .before-connector {
    height: 3px;
    top: $step-size / 2;
    background-color: red;
  }
  > li:first-child span.after-connector,
  > li:last-child span.before-connector {
    background: yellow;
  }
  // completed state
  > li.completed {
    color: $complete;
    .step {
      @include step-style($complete);
    }
  }

  > li.incompleted {
    color: $incomplete;
    .step {
      @include step-style($incomplete);
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

[image]

Comment: would be super helpful if you could provide an image of what it's meant to look like

Comment: Sure Pete, see my update. Cut/paste with paint ;-) please reload pen, did just refactor/extend some classes.

Comment: I updated my question with more information how the process indicator should be built.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lm7kowac/2

Comment: I like it Pete. Some stuff like .text top: 100%; and absolute is good idea. I also scales with more elements correctly and has good responsive behavior. Thanks a bunch. Please make it a solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with a flex solution on the container and move the seperators outside so they can grow equally:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background: orange;
}

.step {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
  background: grey;
}

.text {
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.step:last-child .text {
  right:0;
  left:auto;
}
.seperator {
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.seperator:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.yellow:before {
  background: yellow;
}

.green:before {
  background: green;
}

.red:before {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="step">
    <span class="text">Step 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="seperator yellow"></div>
  <div class="seperator red"></div>
  <div class="step">
    <span class="text">Step 2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="seperator green"></div>
  <div class="seperator red"></div>
  <div class="step">
    <span class="text">Step 3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="seperator green"></div>
  <div class="seperator yellow"></div>
  <div class="step">
    <span class="text">Step 4</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please note you will need to add margin bottom to the container to prevent any content below being overlapped by the text

Comment: Just have seen your margin-bottom comment, I did afair padding-bottom with height of steps value which is 40px :-) thanks.